# Node hijack/mock a requiring of a package

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have to hijack `require('some-package')` so that if anyone in the code does `require('some-package')`, they don't get the original `some-package` but rather something I return, basically what `jest.mock` does.

How can I implement this without using Jest or something else? Is the only option to hijack `require` and check for the package name and conditionally return something else?

Comment: I don't really know what qualifies as "using anything else" but there's a package that basically just does this: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire If nothing else, I'm sure their source could be inspirational